# Clicking a specific item within a drop down list

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having trouble automatically selecting a value from a drop down box button that doesn't have a select type.  I'd like to select and click the "Quarterly" value from the drop-down box labeled "Statement Type", but nothing has worked.  Here's where I'm at so far:

Here's the html:

```
<div class="rf_ctl2_opt">

    <div class="dropdownButton">
        <li id="menu_A" class="r_dd1" onclick="showDropdown1(event,this);">

            <a class="r_ddh1" id="type">
                Annual

            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:SRT_stocFund.ChangeFreq(12,'Annual');">Annual</a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:SRT_stocFund.ChangeFreq(3,'Quarterly')" ;="">Quarterly</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
```

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://financials.morningstar.com/balance-sheet/bs.html?t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US")
import time
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("menu_A")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Quarterly")
```

And this is the error code which I'm getting:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Quarterly"}

Comment: Nothing can happen automatically. First you need to update the question with your code trials along with the relevant HTML and error stack trace then contributors can help you to solve your issue. Please have a look at this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the tip. I updated the question. Kindly let me know if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

As the dropdown is not of the `Select` type, you need to first click on the dropdown menu by using:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("menu_A").click()
```

And you can click on the Quarterly option like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Quarterly']").click()
```

Comment: This question doesn't include either the _code trial_, relevant _HTML_ or the _error stack trace_. Please have a look at this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and stop being a [Help Vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: Thank you Sameer.  Using your code, I'm still unable to make it work.  I'll update my question with my current code and the error that I'm getting.

Comment: @R.Lewis i have made changes in the way i was finding the Quarterly dropdown, please check the updated code.

Comment: @DebanjanB sure, in future, will consider what you have told me.